# searching through a csv file using tkinter

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

ok so
i was able to fit all of the csv file nicely inside tkinter using treeview

here is the code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import csv
 
 
app = Tk()
app.title('Test')
app.geometry('600x200')
 
file = r'C:\Users\Home\Documents\studying\newproject\moviedata.csv'
 
f = open(file, 'r')
csvreader = csv.reader(f)
csvreader_list = list(csvreader)
 
# print(csvreader_list)
 
 
tv = ttk.Treeview(app, columns=('col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3'), show='headings')
tv.column('col_1', minwidth=0, width=400)
tv.column('col_2', minwidth=0, width=100)
tv.column('col_3', minwidth=0, width=100)
 
tv.heading('col_1', text='TITLE')
tv.heading('col_2', text='YEAR')
tv.heading('col_3', text='IMDBID')
 
tv.pack()
 
 
for (i, n, f) in csvreader_list:
    tv.insert('', 'end', values=(i,n,f))
    
app.mainloop()
```

i know how to make an entry and and giving it a stringvar to call later for a search button

but i do not know how to iterate it properly so the user can type for example
search by year: 2020 and it will print all of the movies that was made in 2020
[image: here]

Comment: You could empty the treeview and fill it like you did the first time, just with a condition.

Comment: ye thats what im planing but im not sure how should i wrtie the condition,

Answer (score 0):

ok i tried and tried till it worked
if someone is looking for a solution like this
this is what i have so far im going to edit it to make it cleaner

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import csv
 
 
app = tk.Tk()
app.title('Test')
app.geometry('800x500')
x=StringVar()
y=StringVar()
z=StringVar()
 
file = r'C:\Users\Home\Documents\studying\newproject\moviedata.csv'
 
f = open(file, 'r')
csvreader = csv.reader(f)
csvreader_list = list(csvreader)
 
# print(csvreader_list)


label1=tk.Label(app,text="By Title:",font="Helvetica 12",fg="white",bg="#460B05")
label1.place(x=10,y=10)
search1=tk.Entry(app,textvariable=x)
search1.place(x=80,y=10,height=23,width=200)

label2=tk.Label(app,text="By Year:",font="Helvetica 12",fg="white",bg="#460B05")
label2.place(x=300,y=10)
search2=tk.Entry(app,textvariable=y)
search2.place(x=370,y=10,height=23,width=200)

label3=tk.Label(app,text="By ID:",font="Helvetica 12",fg="white",bg="#460B05")
label3.place(x=580,y=10)
search3=tk.Entry(app,textvariable=z)
search3.place(x=630,y=10,height=23,width=200)




 
 
tv = ttk.Treeview(app, columns=('col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3'), show='headings')
tv.column('col_1', minwidth=0, width=400)
tv.column('col_2', minwidth=0, width=100)
tv.column('col_3', minwidth=0, width=100)
 
tv.heading('col_1', text='TITLE')
tv.heading('col_2', text='YEAR')
tv.heading('col_3', text='IMDBID')
 
tv.place(x=100,y=200)
 
def search():
    
    tv.delete(*tv.get_children())
    word=x.get().title()
    word1=y.get()
    word2=z.get()
    if x.get():
        for (i, n, f) in csvreader_list:
            if word in i:
                tv.insert('', 'end', values=(i,n,f))
    elif y.get():
        for (i, n, f) in csvreader_list:
            if word1 in n:
                tv.insert('', 'end', values=(i,n,f))
    elif z.get():
        for (i,n,f) in csvreader_list:
            if word2 in f:
                tv.insert('', 'end', values=(i,n,f))
    else:
        for (i,n,f) in csvreader_list:
            tv.insert('', 'end', values=(i,n,f))
    search1.delete(0, 'end')
    search2.delete(0, 'end')
    search3.delete(0, 'end')
        

searchbutton=tk.Button(app,text="Search",fg="black",command=search,anchor="center",justify=CENTER)
searchbutton.place(x=1,y=50,width=898)
app.mainloop()
```